# Counterexample of semisimple modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm studying semisimple modules and I found a result in Anderson-Fuller (Proposition 9.4) which says that if
$$ 0 \to N \to M \to M/N \to 0$$
is an exact sequence of modules and $M$ is semisimple, then $N$ and $M/N$ are semisimple. I'm guessing the converse is not true (otherwise I guess it would have been stated in the text) and I'm looking for a counterexample for that, but I don't know were to look. Can anyone give me some guidance? Please DO NOT post a counterexample.

Comment: HINT: if $M$ is semisimple then the sequence splits. So you could begin with trying with a non-split sequence.

Comment: You should look at indecomposable $\mathbb{Z}$-modules for $M$. Can you find one with a simple submodule $N$ such that $M/N$ is also simple?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Look at submodules of $R=\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ as a module over $R$.

Answer (score 2):

Found it! In $\mathbb{Z}$-Mod, take $p$ prime, then:

$$0 \to \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \to \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}/\mathbb{Z}_p \cong \mathbb{Z}_p \to 0$$

and $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ is not semisimple since $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is not a direct summand (that would imply $\gcd(p, p) = 1$, which is false).

Suppose $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2} $ is semisimple, then the above sequence splits and we have
$$ \mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p}$$
and this is true if and only if $\gcd(p,p)=1$ and $p^2 = p \cdot p$, which is false.

Comment: I don't understand your claim that "that would imply $\gcd(p, p^2) = 1$." Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant $gcd(p,p)=1$.

Comment: Okay, but I still don't understand what fact you're trying to apply here. It is in fact the case that $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$, but all you need to do to show this is to observe that the LHS is cyclic and the RHS is not.

Comment: well, that'll do it too, but I guess my answer isn't wrong either.